# Transforming react functional component to a class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/f8t2y?file=/index.js) I'm trying to transform a functional component into class components! I want to achieve nested navigation open only one whenever I click

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Menu } from 'antd';
import { AppstoreOutlined, MailOutlined, SettingOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const { SubMenu } = Menu;

// submenu keys of first level
const rootSubmenuKeys = ['sub1', 'sub2', 'sub4'];

const Sider = () => {
  const [openKeys, setOpenKeys] = React.useState(['sub1']);

  const onOpenChange = keys => {
    const latestOpenKey = keys.find(key => openKeys.indexOf(key) === -1);
    if (rootSubmenuKeys.indexOf(latestOpenKey) === -1) {
      setOpenKeys(keys);
    } else {
      setOpenKeys(latestOpenKey ? [latestOpenKey] : []);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Menu mode="inline" openKeys={openKeys} onOpenChange={onOpenChange} style={{ width: 256 }}>
      <SubMenu key="sub1" icon={<MailOutlined />} title="Navigation One">
        <Menu.Item key="1">Option 1</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="2">Option 2</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="3">Option 3</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="4">Option 4</Menu.Item>
      </SubMenu>
      <SubMenu key="sub2" icon={<AppstoreOutlined />} title="Navigation Two">
        <Menu.Item key="5">Option 5</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="6">Option 6</Menu.Item>
        <SubMenu key="sub3" title="Submenu">
          <Menu.Item key="7">Option 7</Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="8">Option 8</Menu.Item>
        </SubMenu>
      </SubMenu>
      <SubMenu key="sub4" icon={<SettingOutlined />} title="Navigation Three">
        <Menu.Item key="9">Option 9</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="10">Option 10</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="11">Option 11</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="12">Option 12</Menu.Item>
      </SubMenu>
    </Menu>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Sider />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: They are called [Function Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components). They are (generally) not [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).

Comment: What specific problem are you having converting this code to a Class Component? (And why bother? Function Components are generally considered to be the way forwards)

Comment: I created class components but dropdown navigation not working as shown in function components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer this code :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Menu } from "antd";
import {
  AppstoreOutlined,
  MailOutlined,
  SettingOutlined
} from "@ant-design/icons";

const { SubMenu } = Menu;

// submenu keys of first level
const rootSubmenuKeys = ["sub1", "sub2", "sub4"];
class Sider extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      openKeys: ["sub1"]
    };
  }
  onOpenChange = (keys) => {
    const latestOpenKey = keys.find(
      (key) => this.state.openKeys.indexOf(key) === -1
    );
    if (rootSubmenuKeys.indexOf(latestOpenKey) === -1) {
      this.setState({ openKeys: keys });
    } else {
      this.setState({ openKeys: latestOpenKey ? [latestOpenKey] : [] });
    }
  };
  render() {
    const { openKeys } = this.state;
    return (
      <Menu
        mode="inline"
        openKeys={openKeys}
        onOpenChange={this.onOpenChange}
        style={{ width: 256 }}
      >
        <SubMenu key="sub1" icon={<MailOutlined />} title="Navigation One">
          <Menu.Item key="1">Option 1</Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="2">Option 2</Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="3">Option 3</Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="4">Option 4</Menu.Item>
        </SubMenu>
        <SubMenu key="sub2" icon={<AppstoreOutlined />} title="Navigation Two">
          <Menu.Item key="5">Option 5</Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="6">Option 6</Menu.Item>
          <SubMenu key="sub3" title="Submenu">
            <Menu.Item key="7">Option 7</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="8">Option 8</Menu.Item>
          </SubMenu>
        </SubMenu>
        <SubMenu key="sub4" icon={<SettingOutlined />} title="Navigation Three">
          <Menu.Item key="9">Option 9</Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="10">Option 10</Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="11">Option 11</Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="12">Option 12</Menu.Item>
        </SubMenu>
      </Menu>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Sider />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take care of states with declaring it in `constructor`, and you need a `render` method so you can paste your return on it. and whenever you call your class function you need `this` and to update your state, you'll be required `this.setState()`.